# mysql create view of two tables based on id from third

Tags: mysql

I have found a lot of similar posts about merging two tables based on an id from a third, however I just can't seem to work out the logic.

Give
 the three tables

`tableA`

```
| uuid |  ttl  |  ord |
-----------------------
| alpha|  Alp  |     1|
| beta|  Bet  |     2|
| gamma|  Gam  |     3|
```

`tableB`

```
| uuid |  ttl  |  ord | tab_A_ref
--------------------------------
| joe  |  Jo  |     1|  alpha
| mike |  Mi  |     2|  beta
| peter|  Pe  |     3|  alpha
| alan |  Pe  |     4|  beta
| tom  |  Pe  |     5|  gamma
```

`tableC`

```
| uuid |  ttl  |  ord | tab_A_ref
--------------------------------
| jane  |  Ja  |     1|  alpha
| marg  |  Ma  |     2|  beta
| phobe |  Ph  |     3|  alpha
| anon  |  An  |     4|  beta
| toni  |  To  |     5|  gamma
```

I am looking to create a view
`myView` where `tab_A_ref = alpha or beta`

```
| uuid  |  ttl  | ord | tab_A_ref
| joe   |  Jo   |     1|  alpha
| peter |  Pe   |     3|  alpha
| jane  |  Ja   |     1|  alpha
| phobe |  Ph   |     3|  alpha
| mike  |  Mi   |     2|  beta
| alan  |  Pe   |     4|  beta
| marg  |  Ma   |     2|  beta
| anon  |  An   |     4|  beta
```

using the a basic join,

```
SELECT
  tableB.uuid, tableB.ttl, tableB.ord, tableB.tab_A_ref  
  FROM tableB
  INNER JOIN tableA on tableB.tab_A_ref = tableA.uuid
```

I extended the logic to merge the two

```
SELECT
      tableB.uuid, tableB.ttl, tableB.ord, tableB.tab_A_ref,
      tableC.uuid, tableC.ttl, tableC.ord, tableC.tab_A_ref,  
FROM 
      tableB INNER JOIN tableA on tableB.tab_A_ref = tableA.uuid, 
      tableC INNER JOIN tableA on tableC.tab_A_ref = tableA.uuid
```

but that generates an error `not unique table/alias: tableA`

From the other posts it looks like I should have a nested `bracketed` JOIN, having tried a number of combinations all fail. So how do I format the second `JOIN`?

Comment: you are using the `JOIN` incorrectly, the last row just Needs to be `INNER JOIN tableC ON...` and no comma beforehand

Comment: this data structure looks horribly denormalised. Why do tables B and C have identical fields? Surely they should be one table? If they represent something the same but with slightly different properties (e.g. one appears to have male names and one female names) then simply an extra column to make the distinction would be better.

Comment: If all the tableB and tableC rows were just in tableB, then the query (including the restriction to alpha/beta) would simply be `SELECT
      tableB.uuid, tableB.ttl, tableB.ord, tableB.tab_A_ref
FROM 
      tableB INNER JOIN tableA on tableB.tab_A_ref = tableA.uuid WHERE tableA.uuid in ('alpha', 'beta')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All tables (temporary, subqueries, physical or otherwise) must be uniquely named in the query.

Otherwise the database engine has no idea which source of data you're referring to.

**Your original:**

```
SELECT
      tableB.uuid, tableB.ttl, tableB.ord, tableB.tab_A_ref,
      tableC.uuid, tableC.ttl, tableC.ord, tableC.tab_A_ref,  
FROM 
      tableB INNER JOIN tableA on tableB.tab_A_ref = tableA.uuid, 
      tableC INNER JOIN tableA on tableC.tab_A_ref = tableA.uuid
```

In the above, how does the query engine know which `tableA` to use?  You've declared it twice.  Remember you're applying a filter (`ON tableB.tab_A_ref = tableA.uuid`) - so you've got two result-sets (one from the first join, a different one from the second) and they're both referred to as `tableA`.

Simply, use an alias (`AS`) to uniquely reference all tables (joined or otherwise):

```
SELECT
      tableB.uuid, tableB.ttl, tableB.ord, tableB.tab_A_ref,
      tableC.uuid, tableC.ttl, tableC.ord, tableC.tab_A_ref,  
FROM 
      tableB INNER JOIN tableA AS a_ref ON tableB.tab_A_ref = a_ref.uuid, 
      tableC INNER JOIN tableA AS b_ref ON tableC.tab_A_ref = b_ref.uuid
```

Comment: surely it should be `FROM 
      tableB INNER JOIN tableA AS a_ref ON tableB.tab_A_ref = a_ref, 
      INNER JOIN tableC ON tableC.tab_A_ref = tableA.uuid`?

Comment: @ADyson - it could, depending on what he's trying to achieve.  (I find the desired output hard to determine from the OP ... but I'm confident that'll "fix" the error being thrown).  As it is, the query will join everything from tableB to tableC where either table has a matching record in table A.  Syntactically, I believe that's valid (without testing it) - but I agree, doesn't make any "logical" sense without context (and may indeed not give what the OP expected).

Comment: true. Also as I noted above it looks like the data structure might be a bit de-normalised, which is making things more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: @wally, thank you, I saw the `AS` as part of JOIN but did not understand that internally mysql did not alias each query, this clarifies!

Answer (score 0):

The following `JOIN` logic is incorrect:

```
  tableB INNER JOIN tableA on tableB.tab_A_ref = tableA.uuid, 
  tableC INNER JOIN tableA on tableC.tab_A_ref = tableA.uuid
```

The query should be:

```
SELECT
    tableB.uuid, tableB.ttl, tableB.ord, tableB.tab_A_ref  
FROM tableB
    INNER JOIN tableA 
            ON tableB.tab_A_ref = tableA.uuid 
    INNER JOIN tableC 
            ON tableC.tab_A_ref = tableA.uuid
```

The essence of the logic used here is that the first `JOIN` already creates a virtual *unit* that can be joined with any other tables as necessary. `tableA` is already partaking in that `JOIN` and unless there's some special need (which doesn't seem to be the case here), you don't need to specify it again in the query.